# Finding a Mistake for a Particular Form of Inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

My book depicts that the following problem uses ${x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}+{(1+y)\over 8}+{(1+z)\over 8} \ge {3x\over 4} $.

> Let $x, y, z$ be positive real numbers such that $xyz = 1$. Prove that $$ {x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}+{y^3\over (1+z)(1+x)}+{z^3\over (1+x)(1+y)}\geq{3\over 4} $$

and also points the mistake on using $ {x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}+{(1+y)}+{(1+z)} \ge {3x} $ as the equality can not hold.

Why does the equality does not hold?

Comment: For me, it is completly unclear what you are asking. Please try to rephrase and restructure the question and possibly add more details.

Comment: I don't see there a "mistake" : I think that your issue should be formulated in the following way : under condition $C_1$ we can drive conclusion $C$ (for any $x,y,z$), whereas under condition $C_2$, we can not deduce $C$. Therefore you are looking for a conterexample, not a mistake. Besides, you say "the" book : which book ?

Comment: @JeanMarie The problem is from the book Secrets in Inequalities by Pham Kim Hung.

Comment: @BookOfFlames I've mentioned several times to you that when applying inequalities to check if the equality condition holds. In this case, applying $(x,y,z) = (1,1,1)$, we get $ \frac{ x^3}{ (1+y)(1+z)} = 1/4, 1+y = 2, 1 + z = 2$, hence equality cannot hold which means that your inequality is too loose. Whereas Michael's approach gives us variables that are all equal to 1, which means it is not too loose (but doesn't necessarily guarantee that it will work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality $$ {x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}+{(1+y)}+{(1+z)} \ge {3x} $$ is indeed true by AM-GM with the equality for
$$ {x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}=1+y=1+z,$$ which gives $y=z$ and $x^3=(1+y)^3$ or $x=1+y,$ which with the condition $xyz=1$ gives $$(1+y)y^2=1.$$
But in the original inequality the equality occurs for $x=y=z=1$ and we got that your using of AM-GM does not save an equality occurring.

By the way, this AM-GM $${x^3\over (1+y)(1+z)}+{1+y\over 8}+{1+z\over 8} \ge {3x\over 4} $$ saves it.

Comment: Yes. But how can $x=1+y$ with $xyz=1$ lead to $(1+y)(y^2)=1$?And please check if the problem you gave me. I have posted a solution.

Comment: @Book Of Flames Because $\frac{x^3}{(1+y)(1+z)}=1+y=1+z$ gives $y=z$, $\frac{x^3}{(1+y)^2}=1+y$, $x^3=(1+y)^3$ and $x=1+y$. Thus, $1=xyz=(1+y)y^2.$

Comment: And how did $xyz=1$?

Comment: @Book Of Flames See the given. By the way, there are another proofs of your inequality. If you want, I am ready to post them.

Comment: No, but please check the problem you gave on my previous post. Is it correct? Can you provide one more of such kind? And I not can solve it only by AM-GM. How can it be done?

Comment: @Book Of Flames I want that you'll prove it by AM-GM only. Do it and I'll give you another problem.

Comment: I'll try my best to do it. Is the proof posted correct?

Comment: You did not posted a proof. You said some words, but they are not a proof.

Comment: The proof is posted on math.SE, not chat.SE.

Comment: @Book Of Flames I'll say again: It's not a proof. In the contest you will get 1/10 for this "proof".

Comment: For this proof?: Your substitution leads to $5a+12b+13c≥30$ when $2ab+10bc+3ca=15$. By a clever application of AM-GM, the inequality turns to $({2\over \sqrt{ab}}+{10\over \sqrt{bc}}+{3\over \sqrt{ca}})\ge 15$ which is true by Holder, $(2ab+10bc+3ca)({2\over \sqrt{ab}}+{10\over \sqrt{bc}}+{3\over \sqrt{ca}})^2≥15^3$

Comment: @Book Of Flames Show please your "clever application"

Comment: I'm sorry, there was a typo. The first inequality is actually ${5\over a}+{12\over b}+{13\over c}\ge 30$. AM-GM can be applied after this transformation: $({2\over a}+{2\over b})+({10\over b}+{10\over c})+({3\over c}+{3\over a})$

Comment: Now it's true. But I wanted to see a proof by AM-GM only...  OK. It's not needed now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111220/discussion-between-book-of-flames-and-michael-rozenberg).